# How array method(reverse and join) is applied to this string

Tags: javascript

i found this code on internet and i need to know how reverse and join methods in applied here for string

```js
var string = "Welcome to this Javascript Guide!";

// Output becomes !ediuG tpircsavaJ siht ot emocleW
var reverseEntireSentence = reverseBySeparator(string, "");

// Output becomes emocleW ot siht tpircsavaJ !ediuG
var reverseEachWord = reverseBySeparator(reverseEntireSentence, " ");
console.log(reverseEachWord)


function reverseBySeparator(string, separator) {
    return string.split(separator).reverse().join(separator);
}
```

Comment: `split` turns it into an array

Comment: [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). Please, do some basic research before asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let a = "123";
let arr = a.split("");
let revArr = arr.reverse();
let revString = revArr.join("");
console.log(revString);
```

Here we convert the string into array first using split method, then we reverse the array using reverse. Then we convert the array into string again using join method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
var string = "Welcome to this Javascript Guide!";

// Output becomes !ediuG tpircsavaJ siht ot emocleW
var reverseEntireSentence = reverseBySeparator(string, "");

// Output becomes emocleW ot siht tpircsavaJ !ediuG
var reverseEachWord = reverseBySeparator(string, " ");
console.log(reverseEachWord)


function reverseBySeparator(string, separator) {
    return string.split(separator).reverse().join(separator);
}
```